# Is it possible to add ComboBox as ContextMenu item in DataGridView WindowsForms C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, contextmenu, right-click, menu-items

![enter image description here][1]I am trying to add a combobox to ContextMenu on a datagrid when a user right clicks, the menu will pop up. It should show exit and assign to bankID menu options where the bank ID is a combobox dropdown. I did some online search but couldn't find anything close which makes me wonder, it is even possible to do that. I created a mockup image of what I'm trying to do with some code. If anyone has done something similar and share with me, I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

```
    private ContextMenu menuOpp = new ContextMenu();
    private ComboBox cmbAssign = new ComboBox();
    private int currentMouseOverRow;

    private void dataGridView2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            menuOpp.Name = "Exit";
            menuOpp.MenuItems.Add("Exit", new EventHandler(menuItem_Click));
            cmbAssign.Items.Add("assign");

            dataGridView2.ContextMenu = menuOpp;

            currentMouseOverRow = dataGridView2.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;

            menuOpp.Show(dataGridView2, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not a common UI design.  Use a ContextMenuStrip instead so that you can add a ToolStripComboBox control.  What's not clear is when a user interacts with the ComboBox, how or when does it disappear?  The idea has issues.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this myself. I created a ContextMenuStrip, added a MenuItem with sub ComboBox item, populated the ComboBox on ToolStripMenuItem Click event. Then assigned ContextMenuStrip object to its ContextMenuStrip property. After assigning the ContextMenuStrip object to a control, the contextual menu displayed as user right click.

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip Context =
            new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip();

    ToolStripMenuItem mnuAssign = new ToolStripMenuItem("Assign");

    Context.Items.Add(mnuAssign);
    ContextMenuStrip = context;
}
```